# How to declare extern member of class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, extern

Having declared this class:

*vec.hpp*:

```
template<class T>
class Vec
{ 
private:
  T* data; 
  T* avail;
  T* limit;
  extern void create()
  ...
public:
  Vec() {
    create();
  }
};
```

*vec.cpp*:

```
#include "vec.hpp"

template<class T> void Vec<T>::create()
{
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "vec.hpp"

int main()
{
 Vec<int> v;
}
```

Now If I compile it:

```
$ g++ vec.cpp main.cpp

In file included from main.cpp:1:
vec.hpp:55:24: error: storage class specified for ‘create’
     extern void create();
                        ^
In file included from vec.cpp:1:
vec.hpp:55:24: error: storage class specified for ‘create’
     extern void create();
```

It seems I cannot. However the error does not help, it just state, "there is a extern" but does not explain, why it cannot be there. It is true I can ommit the inclusion of `"vec.hpp"` in the `vec.cpp` source, and the linker should later in the `vec.hpp` see, that the `create` function is extern and provided with to `g++` as argument `vec.cpp`, but would it work then? And can I even specify `class storage` (exter, inline, static) in class member declaration in c++?

Comment: What exactly do you intend to achieve by declaring a member function as `extern`? And this won't work for class templates anyway, as you cannot move definitions into a separate "cpp" file

Comment: _"How to declare extern member of class in c++?"_ That's not possible: _"The extern specifier is only allowed in the declarations of variables and functions (except class members or function parameters)."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: The only way to move a template, independent of class member or whatever, to a cpp file is, if you instantiate all instances directly there. This is typically not a useful szenario, so simply don't do it! BTW: Splitting of definitions and declarations feels old fashioned anyway as modern compilers can do so much more optimization if all is in the header file.